# Anaconda not installing properly

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am using a pc running Windows 10.

For some reason every time I try to opening Jupyter, the black window opens for a Split second and shuts down immediately.

After recording my screen I managed to grab a snapshot of the black window...

[image]

Comment: which version of Anaconda do you have installed? Also, try to open the Anaconda prompt and typing `jupyter notebook`. Does this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Activate base in command prompt: (Windows)

```
activate root
```

Step 2: Launch jupyter notebook

```
jupyter notebook
```

Does this work?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The version is Anaconda3-2020.11-Windows-x86_64.

When doing the prompt I get this response: 'activate' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Did you start the anaconda terminal? This error shows when we run the local system's terminal.